# Python : How to store a value generated in a function for the second call of that function

Tags: python

I want to create a random number generation code that inputs "count" number which is that how many times it is called in the program. What I want to do is for the even number of calls of the function I want to create 2 random numbers which are "y1 ,y2" however **I want to output y1 only and** **save y2 for the next call of the function.** So at the odd number of calls the function will directly output y2 of the previous call. Thanks for help. The code so far:

```
import random
import math

def gaussianRandom ( count):
 count += 1
 if count%2 == 0:
  while (1):
   x1 = random.uniform(-1, 1)
   x2 = random.uniform(-1, 1)
   r = x1**2 + x2**2     
   if (r < 1):
    break

  y1 = x1 * math.sqrt( (-2 * math.log(r)) / r )
  y2 = x2 * math.sqrt( (-2 * math.log(r)) / r )

return y1
```

Comment: You could use memoization, but sounds like this would be better solved by a class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I thought so too, was thinking `lru_cache`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

functions can have attributes.

```
import random
import math

def gaussianRandom ( count):
    count += 1
    if count%2 == 0:
        while (1):
            x1 = random.uniform(-1, 1)
            x2 = random.uniform(-1, 1)
            r = x1**2 + x2**2
            if (r < 1):
                break

    y1 = x1 * math.sqrt( (-2 * math.log(r)) / r )
    gaussianRandom.y2 = x2 * math.sqrt( (-2 * math.log(r)) / r )

    print(gaussianRandom.y2)
    return y1

gaussianRandom.y2 = 99
print "y2", gaussianRandom(3)
print gaussianRandom(3)
print gaussianRandom(3)
```

> y2  0.919282832355
>
> -0.0887376744533
>
> y2  -1.71553385287
>
> 0.422645022058
>
> y2  -0.0668389339817
>
> 0.600351205084

Comment: Note that neither this program nor the one in the question maintain `count` as a static variable / function attribute. So it may not do exactly what s900n wants.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need (or want) to tell `gaussianRandom()` how many times you intend to call it? That seems a bit restrictive to me.

I think this problem would be better solved using a generator function. The code below shows how to create one and a couple of ways of how to use it. Rather than implementing your Gaussian algorithm, this generator simply generates numbers of the form 6n±1, so you can easily see what's going on.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Generator demo '''

def gen():
    x = 6
    while True:
        yield x-1
        yield x+1
        x += 6


def main():
    g = gen()
    for i in xrange(10):
        print i, g.next()

    print [(i, v) for i,v in zip(xrange(10), gen())]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**output**

```
0 5
1 7
2 11
3 13
4 17
5 19
6 23
7 25
8 29
9 31
[(0, 5), (1, 7), (2, 11), (3, 13), (4, 17), (5, 19), (6, 23), (7, 25), (8, 29), (9, 31)]
```